# Can I use a friend's Windows XP installer disk for my own computer?

Tags: windows-xp, installation

My friend has a Windows XP installer disk for home and I have a product key for Windows XP home. Would I be able to use his disk to install Windows XP to my computer?

Comment: Make sure his DVD is for XP home and not XP pro. Also there are some DVD's that are OEM specific that you can NOT install on a different brand.

Comment: @Tyson What does that mean then about OEM?

Comment: What brand computer do you have?  What is the **exact** description of the product on the COA (the label with the key) and does it mention a manufacturer?

Comment: @Twisty Dell, just says microsoft xp home edition

Comment: @jack if he has a Dell cd it may accept your key unless it's a Dell key, same with HP, etc

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but make sure the code is correct, and if your code does not work, you have to call a number to get a new code. Wish you luck.

Comment: If the code doesn't work there's a good chance you won't be able to call Microsoft and get that resolved.  They expect you to have the correct media for your product key and you shouldn't proceed assuming they'll bail you out if you don't.  If, however, the product key works fine but fails to activate, that's a different story any in that case calling Microsoft will get the issue resolved (so long as your key is valid [e.g. not stolen]).

Answer (score -1):

As long as your friend's installation disc is "Windows XP Home Edition" and either an OEM disc (says Dell, HP, IBM, etc. on it) or a System Builder disc (says "for distribution with a new PC only" on it), odds are it will work.  It's rare (but not unheard of) for Windows XP-era discs to be BIOS-locked such that an HP/Compaq disc won't work with a Dell key.

Discs that are much less likely to work with your product key are those that say "Upgrade," "Technology Upgrade," or anything about "Volume license".

If you can't afford to find out that your key doesn't work with your friend's disc, then the most effective way to test is temporarily to take your hard drive out of your computer and put another one in, then attempt the installation.  No amount of guessing will substitute for actually seeing it work.  If you don't care if it fails, then go ahead and try it with your own hard drive.

Comment: I'm uncertain how this answer isn't helpful or sufficiently complete, but I'd like to know how to improve it if anyone has a suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

In completion of Twisty's answer I would suggest that you simply "kill" your hard disk instead of replacing it by another one. This must be done from a boot CD. US-DOD is a good algorithm to erase all data from a hard disk. Hope you won't decrease my credits now. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: I suggested using another hard drive "temporarily" as an "effective way to test" whether his key will work with his friend's disc...not as a permanent solution.  If the OP doesn't mind losing all of the data on his drive AND discovering he can't install Windows with his friend's media, then he has no need to test in advance.